# Need assistance trying to web scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-analysis

Very very new to programming - I am trying to scrape a website in order to find get a quick view of some information on site.

Found this on a tutorial on webscraping linked here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests 
    url = raw_input("enter a website to extract URL's from")

    r = requests.get("http://www.pythonforbeginners.com")

    data = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get(href))
```

Error message states "href is not defined". I don't know what else to try... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message is correct. `href` is not defined. Your code expects it to magically appear when you use it in `print(link.get(href))`. Where do you expect `href` to come from?

Comment: try print(link.get('href')) not print(link.get(href))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```